# Plot Feature Importance with feature names

Tags: python, matplotlib, random-forest, seaborn

In R there are pre-built functions to plot feature importance of Random Forest model. But in python such method seems to be missing. I search for a method in `matplotlib`.

`model.feature_importances` gives me following:

```
array([  2.32421835e-03,   7.21472336e-04,   2.70491223e-03,
         3.34521084e-03,   4.19443238e-03,   1.50108737e-03,
         3.29160540e-03,   4.82320256e-01,   3.14117333e-03])
```

Then using following plotting function:

```
>> pyplot.bar(range(len(model.feature_importances_)), model.feature_importances_)
>> pyplot.show()
```

I get a barplot but I would like to get barplot with labels while importance showing horizontally in a sorted fashion. I am also exploring `seaborn` and was not able to find a method.

Comment: You are looking for a `barh` (horizontal bar plot). Pass feature names as  `tick_label`s.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are looking for. Derived a example from [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html). As mentioned in the comment: you can change `indices` to a list of labels at line `plt.yticks(range(X.shape[1]), indices)` if you want to customize feature labels.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier

# Build a classification task using 3 informative features
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000,
                           n_features=10,
                           n_informative=3,
                           n_redundant=0,
                           n_repeated=0,
                           n_classes=2,
                           random_state=0,
                           shuffle=False)

# Build a forest and compute the feature importances
forest = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=250,
                              random_state=0)

forest.fit(X, y)
importances = forest.feature_importances_
std = np.std([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in forest.estimators_],
             axis=0)
indices = np.argsort(importances)

# Plot the feature importances of the forest
plt.figure()
plt.title("Feature importances")
plt.barh(range(X.shape[1]), importances[indices],
       color="r", xerr=std[indices], align="center")
# If you want to define your own labels,
# change indices to a list of labels on the following line.
plt.yticks(range(X.shape[1]), indices)
plt.ylim([-1, X.shape[1]])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I got the features names to appear on the y-axis instead of the index number by replacing this line `plt.yticks(range(X.shape[1]), indices)` for `plt.yticks(range(X.shape[1]), [feature_names[i] for i in indices])`

Answer (score 69):

**Quick answer for data scientists that ain't got no time to waste:**

Load the feature importances into a pandas series indexed by your column names, then use its plot method. For a classifier `model` trained using `X`:

```
feat_importances = pd.Series(model.feature_importances_, index=X.columns)
feat_importances.nlargest(20).plot(kind='barh')
```

---

**Slightly more detailed answer with a full example:**

Assuming you trained your model with data contained in a pandas dataframe, this is fairly painless if you load the feature importance into a panda's series, then you can leverage its indexing to get the variable names displayed easily. The plot argument `kind='barh'` gives us a horizontal bar chart, but you could easily substitute this argument for `kind='bar'` for a traditional bar chart with the feature names along the x-axis if you prefer.

`nlargest(n)` is a pandas Series method which will return a subset of the series with the largest `n` values. This is useful if you've got lots of features in your model and you only want to plot the most important.

A quick complete example using the classic Kaggle Titanic dataset...

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
%matplotlib inline            # don't forget this if you're using jupyter!

X = pd.read_csv("titanic_train.csv")
X = X[['Pclass', 'Age', 'Fare', 'Parch', 'SibSp', 'Survived']].dropna()
y = X.pop('Survived')

model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)

(pd.Series(model.feature_importances_, index=X.columns)
   .nlargest(4)
   .plot(kind='barh'))        # some method chaining, because it's sexy!
```

Which will give you this:

[image: sklearn random forest feature importances]

Comment: what if i wanted to flip this graph on the y axis? as in, have age show first, then fare etc

Comment: @ArtTatum Call `invert_yaxis()` - sample usage `pd.Series(model.feature_importances_, index=X.columns).nlargest(4).plot(kind='barh').invert_yaxis()`

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to just pass `df.columns` as the parameter for `plt.xticks()`:

```
plt.bar( range(len(model.feature_importances_)), model.feature_importances_)
plt.xticks(range(len(model.feature_importances_)), train_features.columns)
plt.show()
```