# XGBoost.save_model loses feature_names when saving

Tags: python, xgboost

I would like to recover the feature names from my saved models, however it seems this info is lost when the model is saved. Steps:

- train model
- feature names exist
- save model using `Booster.save_model`
- load model using `Booster.load_model`
- feature names of loaded model are `None`

Code to reproduce:

```py
import xgboost as xgb

# Prep data
data = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'label': [1, 1, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
y_train = df.pop('label')
x_train = df

# Train model
classifier = xgb.XGBClassifier(
        max_depth=3, 
        learning_rate=0.1, 
        n_estimators=3)
classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)
print(f'Trained, features: {classifier.get_booster().feature_names}')

# Save model
filename = 'test_model.bst'
classifier.save_model(filename)

# Load model
bst_model = xgb.Booster()
bst_model.load_model(filename)
print(f'Loaded: {bst_model.feature_names}')
```

How can I include the feature names in my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it seems, when using `save_model` and `load_model`, the `feature_names` tend to disappear in the loaded model as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54933804/how-to-restore-the-original-feature-names-in-xgboost-feature-importance-plot-af#comment120108156_60155568). However, you can follow this workaround to get back your original feature names:

```
bst_model = xgb.Booster()
bst_model.load_model(filename)
bst_model.feature_names = [df.columns[0], df.columns[1]] # Passing a list of your feature names
```

Although it's hard-coded but it's the only workaround I have seen so far. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65991361/12317368) would be helpful to get more insights.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I had seen those questions you linked but I was hoping there would be some trick, it's a bit strange. If I remember after my vacation in going to raise this as a bug.